# why iphone crashes on direct field (not by getters/setters) acces

Tags: objective-c, ios

[sorry for my weak english]

If I create some NSArray of strings 
(as a member field of an object - no property no synthesize),

and initialise it in -viewdidLoad with some strings by

names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  @"jeden", @"dwa", @"trzy", nil];

and immediately (also in -viewDidLoad) will use it, it is okay.

But when I try use it and its data a little later, in button event handler,
it shows that that array data is corrupted (crashes even on [names count];)

It shows that i need to add property and synthesize and use it by self.names
and then it seem to work... but it is confusing and sad for me because I do
not know what is the reason thet first way of using the member (no self. no property
and synthesize) do not work

could anyone explain,

TIA, fir

Comment: not necessary to add @property, retaining the array is also fine...However, u'll have to use self as you are accessing an entity of the current object - self.

Comment: ok, i understand now that i should retain it or use property with retain (and then i must initialise with self.names= or simply names= is sufficient to fire the setter and make property retain me?); but i do not understand the need of self. if i only retain the array; need I also use self.names too, or it is is not so neccessary

Answer (score 1):

```
names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"jeden", @"dwa", @"trzy", nil];
```

makes an autorelease reference to the object, you need either (both of them increment the retain count by 1):

- make a retain of the object, i mean:

  names = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"jeden", @"dwa", @"trzy", nil] retain];
- or use a new allocation of them, i prefer this approach:

  names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"jeden", @"dwa", @"trzy", nil];

Then in dealloc section don't forget to release it, in order to avoid a memory leak.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize it properly to have it correctly retained:

```
names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"jeden", @"dwa", @"trzy", nil];
```

Comment: I suspect that my first version could be autoreleased butshouldnt it be later - after destroing my containing view?